# Application of degree for maps $S^n \to S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Here is a quote from the book *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher:

> Here is an interesting application of degree:
>
> **Theorem 2.28** *$S^n$ has a continuous field of nonzero tangent vectors iff $n$ is odd*
>
> **Proof:** Suppose $x \mapsto v(x)$ is a tangent vector field on $S^n$, assigning to a vector $x \in S^n$ the vector $v(x)$ tangent to $S^n$ at $x$. Regarding $v(x)$ as a vector at the origin instead of at $x$, tangency just means that $x$ and $v(x)$ are orthogonal in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. If $v(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, we may normalize so that $|v(x)| = 1$ for all $x$ by replacing $v(x)$ by $v(x) / |v(x)|$. Assuming this has been done, the vectors $(\cos t)x + (\sin t)v(x)$ lie in the unit circle in the plane spanned by $x$ and $v(x)$. Letting $t$ go from $0$ to $\pi$, we obtain a homotopy$f_t(x) = (\cos t)x + (\sin t)v(x)$ from the identity map of $S^n$ to the antipodal map $- \mathbb{1}$. This implies that $\text{deg}(-\mathbb{1}) = \text{deg}(\mathbb{1})$, hence $(-1)^{n+1} = 1$ and $n$ must be odd.
>
> Conversely, if $n$ is odd, say $n = 2k-1$, we can define $v(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{2k-1}, x_{2k}) = (-x_2, x_1, \cdots, -x_{2k}, x_{2k-1})$. Then $v(x)$ is orthogonal to $x$, so $v$ is a tangent vector field on $S^n$ and $|v(x)| = 1$ for all $x \in S^n$.

In the proof of Theorem 2.28, I am not getting the need of $x$ and $v(x)$ being orthogonal unit vectors. What if they are not orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Well, $v(x)$ needs to be a **tangent** vector.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future, you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tangent space on the sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076274/tangent-space-on-the-sphere)

Comment: I think the OP is not asking "why is $x$ orthogonal to $v(x)$", but rather, "how is the fact that $x$ and $v(x)$ are orthogonal actually used in the proof". The OP asks, "what is the *need* for $x$ and $v(x)$ being orthogonal". I don't think it's an unreasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $v(x)$ is a tangent vector to $S^n$ at $x$ implies that $v(x)$ is orthogonal to $x$. The fact that $v(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$ means that we can assume without loss of generality that the $v(x)$'s are unit vectors for all $x$, for if they are not to begin with, then you can rescale, as described in the book.

For the remainder of the proof, what's really important is that:

> For all $t \in [0, \pi]$ and $x \in S^n$, the vector $(\cos t) x + (\sin t) v(x)$ lies on $S^n$.

The proof of this requires $v(x)$ to be orthogonal to $x$ (i.e. $v(x).x = 0$), and also requires $v(x)$ to be a unit vector (i.e. $|v(x)|^2 = 1$), for all $x \in S^n$.

Essentially, to prove that the vector $(\cos t) x + (\sin t) v(x)$ lies on $S^n$, you have to show that it has unit norm. The following calculation does precisely this.
\begin{align*} \left| (\cos t) x + (\sin t) v(x) \right|^2 & = (\cos^2 t) |x|^2 + (2\cos t \sin t) (x.v(x)) + (\sin^2t) |v(x)|^2 \\ & = \cos^2 t+\sin^2 t \\ & = 1,\end{align*}

Having established that $(\cos t) x + (\sin t) v(x)$ lies on $S^n$, it makes sense to define a function
$$ F: [0, \pi ] \times S^n \to S^n$$
using the formula
$$ F(t, x) = (\cos t) x + (\sin t) v(x).$$

This $F$ is a homotopy from the identity map $f(x) = x$ to the antipodal map $g(x) = x$. When $n$ is even, no such homotopy can exist since $\text{deg}(f) \neq \text{deg}(g)$. This contradiction proves that the non-vanishing vector field $v$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you! now I understood.